# PHP Order By 2 Or more values Added together

Tags: php, sql, addition, sql-order-by

I'm wondering how to order by 2 Values added together,

I tried this but it didn't work..

```
$q = sprintf("SELECT * FROM Game ORDER BY hitpointsXp DESC + attackXp DESC + strengthXp DESC + defenceXp DESC",
          mysql_real_escape_string($user));
    $getHS = $database->query($q) or die(mysql_error());


if(mysql_num_rows($getHS) == 0){
        //Row code here
}
```

I tried like this, But it didn't work, [See here](http://lazy-scape.online/highscores)

```
$q = sprintf("SELECT * FROM Game ORDER BY hitpointsXp DESC, attackXp DESC, strengthXp DESC, defenceXp DESC",
```

Comment: What do you get in result and what do you want to get? Also add sql tag.

Comment: Trying to Order by hitpointsXp + attackXp + strengthxp + defenceXp added together

Comment: Give us sample data (rows). Also, what means "added together" exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this,

> SELECT *, (hitpointsXp + attackXp + strengthXp + defenceXp) as TotalXp
>   FROM Game ORDER BY TotalXp DESC

Hope it helps.